# How to programmatically sign HCK submission with Extended Validation certificate

Tags: c#, windows, x509certificate2, driver-signing

We have a small app written in C# that we use to sign *.hckx files before they are submitted to Microsoft for signing.

The application code look +/- like this:

```
var workDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(args[0]);
var filesToSign = from item in workDirectory.GetFiles("*.hckx", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) select item.FullName;

X509Certificate2 certificate = getCerticifate();
foreach (var item in filesToSign)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Signing: {0}", item);
  Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Submission.PackageManager.Sign(item, certificate);
  Console.WriteLine("Signing finished");
  var manager = new Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Submission.PackageManager(item);
  Console.WriteLine("Verifying the signature.");
  var signResult = manager.VerifySignature();
  if (signResult != System.IO.Packaging.VerifyResult.Success)
  {
    throw new Exception(String.Format("Verification failed. Expected: {0}, but the result was: {1}.", System.IO.Packaging.VerifyResult.Success, signResult));
  }
}
```

That code works with previous, "regular", certificate.

With new EV certificate there is an additional window displayed that asks for PIN to the certificate.

So the question is:
is there an interface/class that allows to make full sign with EV certificate programmatically?

I would expect PackageManager.Sign method with possibility to provide the PIN as a parameter.

Comment: Have you found a solution? What does `getCertificate()` do in your code? I am facing the same issue. Using the option "Sign using certificate store" throws an error :(

Answer (score 0):

This works for us: in our system there is the EV certificate USB token related "authentication agent" and there in the advanced client settings there is a setting for "single logon" for the agent to ask the USB token password only once and keeps the password until the desktop session is closed. For the desktop check also that no screensaver closes the open desktop. There is also an additional timer setting for "automatic logoff" in the agent settings. We set it to "never". We only need to give the EV token password again if we need to remove the token and attach it back to the system. Then we just run a small script to do a test sign and give the password in the opening dialog.